# How to compute (evaluate) a complex math string

Tags: c#, string, expression, evaluation

I need to evaluate a string like "5*8*9%" so the result should be 3.6.

I tried to use DataTable like this, but it considers this like expressions as invalid (operator is missing):

`DataTable table = new DataTable();`
`table.Compute("5*8*9%",null);`

Is it possible to achieve the result I want using DataTable? Or, is there any other way in C# I can evaluate strings with percent and parenthesis operations without manual parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it without manipulating the string first simply because the percent sign is the modulus operator and any system evaluation of an equation with the % sign will attempt to calculate the mod.

You with either need to write custom code or find some that someone else has already written.

Comment: Thanks, that someone is me :) Ive already implement that, but was trying to see if the system already provides ways doing it for me.